# Matlab fmincon equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a code in matlab and I want to convert it to python. The matlab code is as follows:

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon','algorithm','interior-point','MaxIterations',500);
[theta,feval1,exitflag]=fmincon(@function,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options);
```

I searched for equivalent functions for fmincon in Python and found `Scipy.optimize.fmin`, but when I tried to use it I got stuck in passing the variables. What I have so far is:

```
fmin(function, x0, args=Xdata, maxiter=500)
```

It is clear how to pass the function, the x0, and the number of iterations. but how about the other arguments (`algorithm`, `A`, `b`, `Aeq`, `beq`, `lb`, `ub`, and `nonlcon`)?

Comment: Since you used an interior-point algorithm in Matlab and scipy.optimize.fmin uses a (derivative-free) downhill-simplex algorithm, you should use [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @joni, I did see this function and there are some missing arguments such as Aeq and Beq, how to pass these? Also, I saw the methods used for this function and couldn't see the 'interior-point', so is it used by default by this function?

Comment: The documentation contains several examples of how to pass the constraints, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize). You could use the 'trust-constr' method, which uses [this](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1052623497325107) interior-point algorithm in the presence of inequality constraints. In case you need help, please edit the answer and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).